# How to write python Ternary operator for many conditions

Tags: python

I am trying to write the `python` ternary expression for multiple conditions.

This is how my normal `if` - `else` conditions look like

```
       if globalvariables.is_pending or globalvariables.is_succeeded or globalvariables.is_unknown or globalvariables.is_imagepullbackoff or globalvariables.is_crashloopbackoff:
            if globalvariables.is_pending:
                constants.ICON_ARROWDOWN

            if globalvariables.is_succeeded:
                constants.BLUE

            if globalvariables.is_unknown:
                constants.BRIGHT_CYAN

            if globalvariables.is_imagepullbackoff:
                constants.DARK_GRAY

            if globalvariables.is_crashloopbackoff:
                constants.ICON_CROSS
        else:
            constants.ICON_CHECK
```

normally  the python ternary is look like this:

```
constants.ICON_CHECK if globalvariables.does_kubectl_work_fine else constants.RED+constants.ICON_CROSS
```

How can I write my above code in the format of the ternary operator?

Comment: I wouldn't use a conditional expression here. That'll be messy. A dictionary might work well though. This looks like just a mapping between `globalvaribles` attributes and constants.

Comment: Are you trying to turn that whole block into a single line of code? _Please_ don't do that. Readability is important. There's no prize for cramming code into the fewest number of lines.

Comment: I know but I need to do this. How can I do this?

Comment: @ToRrent Why do you need to? If you really want to, just put the next conditional expression in the `else` but of the previous one. If your teacher is telling you to do that though, it's surely to show you how awful it will turn out.

Comment: Why would you *need* to do this? No developer worth their salt would sacrifice readability over line counts.  I second a `dict` approach per @Carcigenicate.  If you however insist you can chain the conditions like `x1 if x else y1 if y else z1 if z else ...`

Comment: @r.ook I'm actually questioning using a dictionary now because it actually looks like it's just boolean flags, which wouldn't work well with a dictionary. With how it's set up now, I might just keep this code as it is.

Comment: If they incorporated a `class State(Enum):` (assuming each above flag state is exclusive of the others), you could just do `PENDING = constants.ICON_ARROWDOWN` (and a similar line for each other state option), the use the enum instead of separate flags, and do `PENDING.value` to get the icon.

Comment: Why would you assume that the flags are exclusive?

Comment: @Neil Provided the flags are referring to the same underlying state, `is_succeeded` and `is_pending` seem exclusive, even if they aren't using `elif` here.

Answer (score 0):

The ternary operator specifically supports 3 parts (hence "ternary"). You'd have to use nested ternary operators to accomplish this. Like:

```
constants.ICON_ARROWDOWN if globalvariables.is_pending else (constants.BLUE if global_variables.is_succeeded else (constants.BRIGHT_CYAN if globalvariables.is_imagepullbackoff else (...))
```

However, that's kind of a mess. You should probably listen to @Carcigenicate and use a dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

You can't. John's answer would be correct *if* you were doing an if-elif branch. But actaully, the way your original code is set out, it is possible for both

```
constants.BRIGHT_CYAN
```

and

```
constants.DARK_GRAY
```

to occur, for example. Your branches aren't exclusive. Whereas, if you chain ternary operators, only one of these could trigger at most.
There is no other way to use the ternary operator. So if what you want is to reproduce your logic using the ternary operator, you can't.

Answer (score 0):

`elif` clauses would be more beneficial, as you don't need to check each variable twice:

```
    if globalvariables.is_pending:
        x = constants.ICON_ARROWDOWN
    elif globalvariables.is_succeeded:
        x = constants.BLUE
    elif globalvariables.is_unknown:
        x = constants.BRIGHT_CYAN
    elif globalvariables.is_imagepullbackoff:
        x = constants.DARK_GRAY
    elif globalvariables.is_crashloopbackoff:
        x = constants.ICON_CROSS
    else:
        x = constants.ICON_CHECK
```

Ironically, doing so suggests a way to use nested conditional expressions, though I'm not sure it's really a huge improvement over `if` statement above:

```
x = (constants.ICON_ARROWDOWN if globalvariables.is_pending else
     constants.BLUE if globalvariables.is_succeeded else
     constants.BRIGHT_CYAN if globalvariables.is_unknown else           
     constants.DARK_GRAY if globalvariables.is_imagepullbackoff else
     constants.ICON_CROSS if globalvariables.is_crashloopbackoff else
     constants.ICON_CHECK)
```

Comment: Again, this is not equivalent to the code that the OP had. Why assume that these are exclusive?

Comment: At the moment, the OP's code doesn't do anything; the constants aren't assigned or otherwise used in a larger expressions. However, the first condition implies they are exclusive, because if one is false, the ones the follow aren't even looked at. The names of the constants also imply they don't combine.

Comment: yes they are. Look again. The fact that they aren't assigned doesn't mean that the OPs code doesn't do anything. They could be properties with logic built in.

Comment: Highly unlikely. I'll welcome feedback from the OP if this is insufficient.

Comment: It's quite likely that the OP made a mistake by not using elif. But you can't assume that. This code doesn't something different to what the OP asked for.

Comment: You should at least warn about that

Comment: *Not about it being insufficient. About it being potentially misleading.

Comment: @Neil I mean, you're assuming that they *aren't* exclusive based on the same vague code.